# Unable to git commit

Tags: git, husky

When I commit, I get the following husky error.

I ran `npx --version` to see if npx was installed.
It showed `8.0.0`.
After running `rm -rf .husky`, I did another git commit, but it didn't solve the problem.

**error**

```
.husky/pre-commit: line 4: npx: command not found
husky - pre-commit hook exited with code 127 (error)
```

Comment: Does your pre-commit hook specify the full path to npx?

Comment: Not specified.
I use sourcetree to do git operations.

Comment: Is your terminal configured so that *it* knows the path to npx, but SourceTree might not be?

Comment: Where can I see the npx settings?

Comment: I think I can solve this problem by writing the npx path in the ~/.huskyrc file, but I don't know how to open the ~/.huskyrc file.

Comment: For me, the problem was that my code really had lint errors (I set up pre-commit to run lint). However, instead of showing a log or message, I got `husky - pre-commit hook exited with code 127 (error)`. Probably because of wrong configuration.

Comment: `git commit -m "message" --no-verify`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

npx husky-init
npm install

[image]

npm run prepare

Comment: [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't
be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead,
paste the code as text directly into your
question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four
spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Answer (score 1):

For me this is caused by missing Git path in Advanced System Settings > Environment Variables > System Variables > Path

The missing value is one of

```
C:\Program Files\Git\cmd
C:\Program Files\Git\bin
```

Add this and then restart your Git environment. This is from a comment at the bottom of this thread https://github.com/typicode/husky/issues/1038

This happens to me in Visual Studio, usually after an update this is missing and needs to be re-added.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://typicode.github.io/husky/#/?id=command-not-found) is the vendor's answer to this issue:

But if you don't want to spend time reading Husky docs, and if you are using nvm for using multiple versions of Node, every time you open a new terminal tell it which Node version you want to use. It means in the terminal of your git cli (where you "git commit ..."), do:

nvm use 12.12.12
(With your desired Node version of course)

Answer (score 0):

For me, none of the solutions here worked. I had to reinstall Node.js.
I didn't download it via the CLI, but rather the official site: https://nodejs.org/en/download/

Not sure if that makes a difference but that's how I downloaded & fixed it.
I hope it can help someone else out too!

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue but for me this works as mentioned above but just to clarify how to do it using yarn I have followed below steps

First I have faced below error as mentioned below

[image]

**Step - 1:** Delete the **node modules** and `yarn.lock` file first install the node modules using `yarn`.

**Step - 2:** Then run `yarn prepare` which installs the `husky` package

[image]

**Step - 3:** Now I can run git commit without the above error as shown below.

[image]